# Iptables from udp to tcp

Tags: tcp, udp, port, iptables

Is it possible to convert all outgoing **udp** traffic from a gateway router to **tcp** on the same port with iptables. Have looked at mangle but unsure how I can use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in a generic way for at least the following reasons:

- UDP is a datagram protocol, where each packet is independent from the other. TCP instead is a stream protocol. While it would be possible to concatenate the UDP packets to a TCP stream it is not clear at which boundaries the TCP stream should be split to generate the packets.
- With UDP duplicates, packet loss and reordering of packets could happen. If you cannot be sure about the proper order and that you got all messages and exactly once you can not construct reliable a TCP stream from it.
- TCP acknowledges when it receives packets and if an ACK is missing the packet gets retransmitted. Once you forward TCP to UDP these ACKs can not be done because UDP does not have such mechanism.

It might still be possible to do application specific translations, like UDP DNS to TCP DNS or similar. But this translation depends on the application protocol so you need to have an application specific gateway. iptables as a packet filter works on a lower layer and does not provide such functioniality.